# Setting up React / Redux typescript for hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks

I've been looking at different resources online trying to find a working solution for what I have and so far I think I'm kinda botching my typescript integration. I'd love to have some help in properly setting up my types for my hook.

I have a `useUser()` hook that dispatches actions to my reducer and also returns selectors back from my store. I've made some progress, but I'm starting to get in over my head a little bit.

the hook: `useUser.ts`

- I'm not sure what I can place as the return for this hook. I tried placing `useUserActionTypes` but I don't think that makes any difference, especially since I'm not returning anything really beyond either getting an object (`userData`), or a number
  (`totalPoints`, `totalWords`) from the store.
- I dont think I should be "returning" my dispatches, but it made typescript less upset
- I can also just type in something like 'Dog' instead of `FETCH_USER` into my dispatch's type for example. Probably doesn't matter, but I think there should be a safeguard in there, right?
- Pretty stumped with how to actually fix that error in the destructured return. I have a type called `User` that represents an object that my store will have for user, but ... that made no difference.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import { User } from '../reducers/user';

export const FETCH_USER = 'FETCH_USER';
export const UPDATE_ERRORS = 'UPDATE_ERRORS';
export const INCREMENT_POINTS = 'INCREMENT_POINTS';
export const INCREMENT_WORDS = 'INCREMENT_WORDS';

type Error = {
  code: number;
  message: string;
};

type FetchUserAction = {
  type: typeof FETCH_USER;
  payload: User;
};

type UpdateErrorsAction = {
  type: typeof UPDATE_ERRORS;
  payload: Error[];
};

type IncrementPointsAction = {
  type: typeof INCREMENT_POINTS;
  payload: number;
};

type IncrementWordsActions = {
  type: typeof INCREMENT_WORDS;
};

// ? Typescript is able to infer the correct type in the Union Type below
export type useUserActionTypes =
  | FetchUserAction
  | UpdateErrorsAction
  | IncrementPointsAction
  | IncrementWordsActions;

export type ReduxStore = {
  alert: any;
  user: User;
};

const useUser = (): useUserActionTypes => {
  const userData: User = useSelector((state: ReduxStore) => state.user);
  const totalPoints: number = useSelector(
    (state: ReduxStore) => state.user.points
  );
  const totalWords: number = useSelector(
    (state: ReduxStore) => state.user.words
  );
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fetchUser = async (): Promise<FetchUserAction | UpdateErrorsAction> => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/WhpHq4qWFdzlhlx2ztqD'
      );
      const user = response.data;
      return dispatch({
        type: FETCH_USER,
        payload: user,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_ERRORS,
        payload: [
          {
            code: 500,
            message: error.message,
          },
        ],
      });
    }
  };
  const incrementPoints = (amount: number): useUserActionTypes => {
    return dispatch({
      type: INCREMENT_POINTS,
      payload: amount,
    });
  };
  const incrementWords = (): useUserActionTypes => {
    return dispatch({
      type: INCREMENT_WORDS,
    });
  };
  return {
    userData,
    totalPoints,
    totalWords,
    fetchUser,
    incrementPoints,
    incrementWords,
  };
};

export default useUser;
```

[image]

---

On a page where I am trying to use the selectors:

- I thought these were covered in my hook, I have types assigned to these constants.
- `fetchUser()` returns a type of 'any' ... same issue as above perhaps?

[image]

[image]

Thank you for any help, It's definitely fun trying to get this all properly hooked up with typescript but I am a bit lost currently.

Comment: useUserActionTypes type is wrong type for useUser return, useUser was typed to return a single action (an object with type and payload keys) while it actually returns multiple things with fetchUser being action creator and not an action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you incorrectly typed `useUser`, the correct return type according to your code would be:

```
{
    userData: User;
    totalPoints: number;
    totalWords: number;
    fetchUser(): Promise<FetchUserAction | UpdateErrorsAction>;
    incrementPoints(amount: number): useUserActionTypes;
    incrementWords(): useUserActionTypes;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDK6A26DGM0ANChgCLCpgCGM+AFnAL5wBmUEIcA5FOjUIBafgBNkADx4BuAFChIsODQnAIqdp248Va1DPnho8JAFUMUFpq68AdLYD0Y5PnRRUDtG4Oz0ExfD4EAB2qPAAYgCiACoAwgASAPqmmJEASnAAvLxRcUkp6QZ+AXBBofCmAArkAILRkYnpaQDyaZhZvFW19Y1pLW1F-salIWFwAJIAcrFpkQCykZPRiZXNU9Ht2TxTM-OLy6vrmIMlZWM7swtLiQDqreSbvBd713dpDz4wAJ5g6HCRUE4lmyCFkcBGonQAC44MFkCAAEZuOTgkDoVCoGgAc2hcDCUGAwSxcmYclk31+cHC6HoDHMbhqhDUwQ6oPBFNxHIgbCpMQSyVSaRRcFoXxwEBoohh9KgJLJHLgpjAojo6ABQNQjJgzNZYLgHJhXJ5XTqDSarUwwtF4slMPV0AA2gBdOWyck-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-jZwRpXN6XSTAUBfET0kjOD-DUKMfww0eNDAPAujqLYOIwGdFPsTwDAwDAYBQl24r4PhDDqDAUIAKwAAyyw4NBgMADgAG4AIyeBYHg3AwYDxAAjgALHrNzhKIABeOAMDgEgAExmzAevkDwI3gutXOZeRHTU5AoSPeZNDheC-AwMgUAst9QO0gxbFcwavJ5AK6TEC77HpraWXJ1zzBu+xrAi39DFuEC9Ux+xweh+HP3Aww0cp5GvzStUpq9P0mCZ1zIo0GKGYwg6dfsaXHcQriMvS+3Q+ouimI4jCRfQLYaIYti6Djx3zCr9JTobywOfgswer5uCmVOTBAZBqJjEeV5Pm9TmAV0QySWDg1pfl2HX1V1Hg8NrizaJocKZt5p0zFfbyMBV7Z2FIfSmYwT5RVgrFRi98MAYxCKFF+I036V0jiDb+cc-6vHuG3EakCD7CiweTcE5Eco0FXp1YS58Qx0O2nJWKq9VKvgsKvOBLlGGoG4ZFUsu1275nzKeEokI2A0GQDgWiKCqJAA)